# (WPF, Data Binding, DependencyProperty) Can I get only the list of specific member variables in the list?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, dependency-properties

First of all, the main purpose of this question is to make it easy for other team members to use my code in viewmodel. It's a question of good code design for cooperation. Therefore, DependencyProperty is used, and Data Binding is also used.

What I want to do is that if the user adds a value to the my DependencyProperty list, the content corresponding to the entire UI is automatically applied with data binding. In the example, it will be a ComboBox. Display a list in ItemsSource property, and check the selected item with SelectedItem property.

So I wrote the code as below. But, in the list of user-defined type MyData, I was stuck in the data binding of the list for a specific member(Data1, Data2, Data3 in MyData class) to the ComboBox control.

From the beginning, the code design may have been wrong. Ask for advice. The code is below.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public class MyData
    {
        public MyData(int data1, int data2, int data3)
        {
            Data1 = data1;
            Data2 = data2;
            Data3 = data3;
        }
        public int Data1 { get; set; }
        public int Data2 { get; set; }
        public int Data3 { get; set; }
    }

    public List<MyData> MyDataList
    {
        get => (List<MyData>)GetValue(MyDataListProperty);
        set => SetValue(MyDataListProperty, value);
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyDataListProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "MyDataList", typeof(List<MyData>), typeof(MainWindow), new UIPropertyMetadata(new List<MyData>()));

    public MyData CurrentMyData
    {
        get => (MyData)GetValue(CurrentMyDataProperty);
        set => SetValue(CurrentMyDataProperty, value);
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentMyDataProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "CurrentMyData", typeof(MyData), typeof(MainWindow), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = this;

        MyDataList.Add(new MyData(1, 2, 3));
        MyDataList.Add(new MyData(4, 5, 6));
        MyDataList.Add(new MyData(7, 8, 9));
        CurrentMyData = MyDataList[1];
    }
}
```

```
<TextBox  Width="120" Height="23" Margin="76,160,596,236"
    Text="{Binding CurrentMyData.Data2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

<ComboBox  Width="189" Height="34" Margin="291,160,312,225"
    ItemsSource="{Binding <!-- list for Data3 -->, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding <!-- and selected item. CurrentMyData.Data3 ? -->, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Comment: One of the purposes is, for example, to show the contents of Data3 member of MyData as a list of ComboBox. If the user adds MyData to MyDataList, a new Data3 member value is automatically added. In the actual example above, the Integer values 3, 6, and 9 will be shown in the list of the ComboBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ItemsSource can contain however complex objects. If ComboBox should show only one property, set DisplayMemberPath:

```
<ComboBox 
    ItemsSource="{Binding MyDataList}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentMyData}"
    DisplayMemberPath="Data3"/>
```

to show many properties change ItemTemplate:

```
<ComboBox 
    ItemsSource="{Binding MyDataList}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentMyData}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>        
        <DataTemplate>            
            <StackPanel>                
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Data1}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Data2}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Data3}"/>                
            <StackPanel>            
        </DataTemplate>        
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>    
</ComboBox>
```